# JavaScript Puzzle: Initialize 2 Date variables with same value, but in result they represent different calendar dates

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Please take a look at my screenshot, I am clearly missing something here.

The variables **tmpStart** and **itemDate** are initialized by the **same numeric value**, but it shows that they have **different calendar date**.

- start = 1490683782833  ->  tmpStart = "Sun Mar 26 2017 16:51:55 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
- item = 1490683782833   ->   itemDate = "Tue Mar 28 2017 08:49:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)"

[image]

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: **DON'T USE SCREENSHOTS FOR CODE**. No one will be able try it out since nobody wants to retype it.

Comment: You are making start += itemSize  and asking why itemDate is not the same as tmpStart?

Comment: No, I am asking why tmpStart & itemDate represent different calendar date when they are initialized by start & item, which have same numeric value.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mcve] and place the code in the question itself as text, not as images.

Comment: Because you are summing it with start...

Comment: To clarify the above: you are adding itemSize to start AFTER you have used start to initialise tmpStart.  If you did the addition first, then tmpStart would == itemDate on your first loop iteration

Comment: @bobtato, thanks for explaining me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 let tmpStart = new Date(start);
 start += itemSize; // start changed

 // item === start (changed value)
 let itemDate = new Date(item);

 // therefore
 tmpStart != itemDate
```

That's why.

Embrace functional programming. Don't do assignment. :) (`start += itemSize`)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a different instance of date each time you are using new Date() ,so they would be different

Comment: Yes, but I am initializing it with same numeric value, so they should represent same calendar date.